# What's exactly "Available" keying set?

Tags: animation, keyframes, dopesheet

Most keying sets are pretty self-explanatory. Like `Loc` or `LocRotScale`. But what's `Available`?

[image]

The [official document](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/keyframes/keying_sets.html#keying-set-panel) doesn't say anything about it either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Available keying set is the set for keys that were created by keyframing an *Available* Key.

When you create a keyframe, you create one or more F-Curves, or you add that keyframe to an existing set of F-Curves.

As the tooltip says when you hover over Available in the keyframe menu, it inserts a keyframe on each of the already existing F-Curves.

The Available keying set is often used with automatic key generation.  The workflow is to go to frame 0 or 1 and set a keyframe for each property you want to change.  Then you enable the Available keying set and turn on automatic keyframing.

This way, when you move the frame and then modify state, only the bits you want to include show up in the keyframe that is automatically added.

This is very useful when creating actions in the NLA.

[image: definition]

Answer (score 3):

It looks like *Available* will create a keyframe for the transforms that have already been keyframed. If you have already created keyframe for *Location* and *Rotation* (but not *Scale*) and now for some frame you create a new keyframe > *Available* type, it will only create a *Location* + *Rotation* keyframe, no *Scale* keyframe, even though you've scaled the object at this frame.